# How to compute (2^32)/n using 32-bit integers

Tags: algorithm, math, 32-bit

I have a 32-bit timer which I want to overflow after n steps. This means each step should be (2^32)/n. However, if I try to compute this number using 32-bit integers, the compiler complains that (1<<32) is larger than the type I'm using.

I could come quite close to the answer I'm looking for by instead doing something like (~0)/n. However, it bugs me that in this case I would not get the correct answer when n is a power of 2, which means in those cases it would take one extra step for the timer to overflow.

Is there a simple expression to calculate (2^32)/n using only 32-bit integers?

Comment: How do you want to round the result? If you round toward 0, then the timer will overflow on the 4th step for n=3.

Comment: (2^32)/n = 2*((2^31)/n)

Comment: @ScottHunter - not with integer arithmetic.  E.g. (2^32)/3 = 1431655765 <> 2*((2^31)/3) = 1431655764.

Comment: @user2357112 Fair point. I suppose I would want to round up, or alternatively compute (2^32+n-1)/n.

Comment: This looks an [XY-problem](http://xyproblem.info/): to distribute the steps as evenly as possible *and* get as close to 2^32 as to zero, have a look at [Bresenham's algorithm](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham's_line_algorithm#Method).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the counter to overflow on precisely the nth step (when this is possible), then you need to compute `ceil(232 / n)`. Consider the two possible cases:

1. n is not a power of 2. In this case, n is not a factor of `232`, and the ceiling of the division is exactly one more than the floor. Moreover, (using truncating integer division, as in C or Java) `floor(232 / n) == floor((232 - 1) / n)`. So the desired step is `(232 - 1)/n + 1`.
2. n is a power of 2. In this case, n precisely divides `232`, and so `(232 - 1) / n` will be one less than `232 / n`. So the desired step is `(232 - 1)/n + 1`. Conveniently, that's the same value as in the first case.

**Note:** As @greybeard notes in a comment, there no guarantee that an appropriate step size exists if `n > 216`. For larger `n`, the above procedure will compute the largest step size which guarantees that overflow will not occur before step `n`.

Comment: `overflow on precisely the nth step` won't happen for all `n` > 2^16.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using C as your programming language, you can use its unsigned arithmetic. Consider the following:

```
floor(232 / n) = floor((232 - n) / n + 1)
```

If your `n` has an unsigned type (e.g. `uint32_t`), then the mathematical expression `232 - n` can be calculated as simply `-n`.

So in C:

```
uint32_t n = ...;
uint32_t d = (-n) / n + 1;
```

Alternatively:

```
uint32_t d = (0 - n) / n + 1;
```

You should document it well, because this is really obscure code.